# How to create a bezier instruction on top of UISlider?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How do i create an popup/instruction/coach mark in ios objective-C on top of UISlider? I tried using https://github.com/spromicky/StepSlider but couldn't come up with an instruction on top of the slider.

[instruction_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXE37.png)

Comment: Have you tried to just make labels and change their text or show them depending on the slider values? What is your goal?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/alskipp/ASValueTrackingSlider